# IN query to select ALL records

Tags: sql-server

I tried with this query but no luck :

```
SELECT tr.transferfrom, tr.transferto, br.id as 'BR_ID',
  tr.refno, br.name as 'BR_NAME', br.code as 'BRANCH_CODE',
  tr.docno, tr.transdate, stk.stockno,stk.salescat,tr.qty,
  tr.sprice,tr.qty*tr.sprice as 'GROSS_SALES' 
FROM TRANSFER tr 
JOIN branch br on tr.branchid=br.id 
JOIN stocks stk on tr.stockid=stk.id 
WHERE (tr.docno = 'ST00576' AND br.id IN ('*')) 
OR RIGHT(tr.refno,7) = 'ST00576' AND LEFT(tr.refno,3) IN ('*')
```

I wanted to have query to select ALL records if the `br.id` is a blank value.

Comment: Can a column called `id` really be blank in your schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a subquery that gets all the branch ids and then the `IN` query can refer to the output of the subquery.. the subquery will be like `select br.id from branch br`

Thus the entire query will look like:

```
SELECT 
  tr.transferfrom, 
  tr.transferto, 
  br.id as 'BR_ID',
  tr.refno,
  br.name as 'BR_NAME', 
  br.code as 'BRANCH_CODE', 
  tr.docno,
  tr.transdate, 
  stk.stockno,
  stk.salescat,
  tr.qty,
  tr.sprice,
  tr.qty*tr.sprice as 'GROSS_SALES' 
FROM TRANSFER tr 
  JOIN branch br 
    on tr.branchid=br.id 
  JOIN stocks stk 
    on tr.stockid=stk.id
WHERE (
  tr.docno = 'ST00576' 
  AND br.id IN (select br.id from branch br)
  ) 
  OR RIGHT(tr.refno,7) = 'ST00576' 
  AND LEFT(tr.refno,3) IN ( select br.id from branch br)
```

Comment: forgot to mention the '*' are comma separated value and can possibly be blank..it is a user input from checkbox which I concatenate them as comma separated ..but sometime user couldleave it blank to including all branchid..